# MySQL view with SET @variables & specific SELECT query

Tags: mysql

Please advise how can I create a View based on a query with the following parameters?
I know there's recommendation for using Functions, but I do not understand how in my case I can utilize them. Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '`', COLUMN_NAME, '`' SEPARATOR ',') FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE table_name = 'WH_source' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%-03-%' INTO @filtered;

SET @table = 'WH_source';
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT LEFT(`Mapping Model#Suffix`,INSTR(`Mapping Model#Suffix`,".")-1), ',@filtered,' FROM ', @table);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: View is statically stored SELECT query. It cannot contain any SQL code except SELECT query.

Comment: Why do you need a view for this? It seems this is in a function/procedure. This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) please explain your case

Comment: This code parses original table and outputs it in the way user should see it. As Query cannot be used, I need to have View. I know that view supports only SELECT, but I can't avoid using vairables. To be more precise I can explicitly point 'WH_source" in CONCAT function and avoid using '@table' variable. But I can't avoid using '@s'. Please help to reformat so that based on above SQL I could have View.

Comment: First I select columns from initial table (I need to filter by Current month parsing, e.g. 03 - March), after that I SELECT necessary fields. If Functions can help, would you please advise how to restructure my code to the one using functions?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to avoid using variables but now faced different problem - cannot apply function or procedure. First one cannot return query data, and second cannot be used in a view.
My input file is something like this (field names are constantly changing, but contain Week number which I would like to parse in ideal case and restructure it dynamically so that it could be used in a view):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Edn.png)

Weeks in source change on a weekly basis, so I cannot SELECT explicitly pointing field names.
I need filter my View in the way it should display only current month data.
But it looks impossible, because I can only filter it with non-friendly operators for the View. Any suggestion on how to reach this?